# Getting an email address instead of a name?

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, interop

When I am trying to printout the different properties in a `MailItem`, I am seeing some behavior that I don't understand. Instead of email addresses, I see names.

```
static void ReadMail()
{
     Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application app = null;
     Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._NameSpace ns = null;
     Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder inboxFolder = null;

     app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
     ns = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");

     inboxFolder = ns.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);

      for (int counter = 1; counter <= inboxFolder.Items.Count; counter++)
      {
           dynamic item = inboxFolder.Items[counter];
           Console.WriteLine("Sendername: {0}", item.SenderName);
           Console.WriteLine("Sender: {0}", item.Sender);
           Console.WriteLine("To: {0}", item.To);
       }
 }
```

What I mean is instead of getting "john.doe@email.com", I am getting "John Doe". Any particular reason this might be happening? Is there a way to obtain the email address of the sender and the recipients (To, CC, BCC) instead of names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you should use `item.SenderEmailAddress` instead of `item.SenderName`.

Also you can iterate collection `item.Recipients` to determine Sender/TO/CC/BCC addreses(type is stored in `Type` property of each Recipient object of that collection) - it has one of `Outlook.OlMailRecipientType` enumeration values(olOriginator, olTo, olCC, olBCC).

Comment: Unfortunately I'm getting the same problem when I used `SenderEmailAddress`. I'm seeing a string like this: `/OU=EXCHANGE ADMINISTRATIVE GROUP...` Let me try the other approach you mentioned.

Comment: Ok, even when I iterate, I see the same string as the one output by `SenderEmailAddress`. Any other ideas?

Comment: This link: http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Server_Software/Email_Servers/Exchange/Q_27962937.html suggests it has to do with one of the Exchange server settings `LegacyexchangeDN`. I have no idea why that is propagating all the way to COM Objects.

Comment: It's tottaly correct X.500-standart email address, which is used by client software inside exchange-network.. When it's like that, you can use property `AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress` of Recipient object to get SMTP-standard email address.

Comment: @Legend, in some scenarios it can be little troublesome to rely ExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress property and on ExchangeUser object isself - user can have hundreds of SMTP(and other) addresses associated with ExchangeUser(sometimes you may want to get them all, instead of  only primary). It can have no Smtp-addresses at all. Also Recipient may have no user in Exhange. So you need some checks in code.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using the `To`/`CC`/`BCC` properties, loop through all recipients in the MailItem.Recipients collection and read the Recipient.Address property. You might also want to use the Recipient.Type (olTo / olCC / OlBCC) property.

```
foreach (Outlook.Recipient recip in item.Recipients)
{
   if (recip.Type == (int)OlMailRecipientType.olTo)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Name: {0}, address: {1})", recip.Name, recip.Address));
   } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you give me an example of using olTo or olCC?

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't comment the answer,

You need to cast one of the if member because otherwise it will says that it can not compare an `int` type with an `OlMailRecipientType` and the compilation will fail.

here I cast the `OlMailRecipientType.OlTo` to an `int`

`if (Recip.Type == (int)OlMailRecipientType.olTo)`

```
foreach (Outlook.Recipient recip in item.Recipients)
{
   if (Recip.Type == (int)OlMailRecipientType.olTo)
   {
      Console.WriteLIne(string.Format("Name: {0}, address: {1)", recip.Name, recip.Address));
   } 
}
```